# cumsum according to certain restricts in r

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a large data of car accidents and a sample of it is provided below.

- `accident` is a binary variable of whether the accident happens or
  not.
- `shift_number` is the number of the shift, 0 means the driver is
  taking a rest and not a shift.
- `time_diff` is the amount of time at each observation.

  ```
  df <- data.frame(
  accident     = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  shift_number = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  time_diff    =   3:17
  )
  ```

My question is to measure the total amount of working time since the driver starts this shift for each accident.

```
wanted <- data.frame
(
  accident     = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  shift_number = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  time_diff    = 3:17,
  cum_time     = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 75)
)
```

Does anyone have ideas on solving this problem with R? It's better to have data.table or vectorised solution because I've got huge data to deal with.

Comment: It is not clear to me how `cum_time` is calculated.

Comment: @Ronak Shah cum_time of each accident is the cumsum of "time_diff" at the start of that shift, to the point where the accident actually happens

Answer (score 3):

```
df$cum_time = 0
accident = which(df$accident == 1)

df$cum_time[accident] <- sapply(accident, function(x) {
    sum(df$time_diff[(which.max(cumsum(df$shift_number[1:x] == 0)) + 1): x])
})

df

#   accident shift_number time_diff cum_time
#1         0            1         3        0
#2         0            1         4        0
#3         0            0         5        0
#4         0            0         6        0
#5         0            0         7        0
#6         0            2         8        0
#7         0            2         9        0
#8         0            2        10        0
#9         0            0        11        0
#10        0            0        12        0
#11        0            3        13        0
#12        1            3        14       27
#13        0            3        15        0
#14        0            3        16        0
#15        1            3        17       75
```

We first make all the values in `cum_time` variable as 0. We find the indices where `accident` has occurred. For each of those indices we find the latest 0 in `shift_number` and calculate the sum of values of `time_diff` from the latest 0 to `x` and assign it to its respective indices.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ave` function to compute the cumulative sum of `time_diff` by `shift_number`:

```
cumsum_by_shift <- ave(df$time_diff, df$shift_number, FUN=cumsum)
#[1]  3  7  5 11 18  8 17 27 29 41 13 27 42 58 75
```

Pick out elements of `cumsum_by_shift` where accidents occur:

```
cum_time <- ifelse(df$accident == 1, cumsum_by_shift, 0)
#[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 27  0  0 75
```

Note the use of the vectorized `ifelse` function.

Comment: Nice thinking but I think you are missing something here. Try doing `df$shift_number[14] <- 0` and recalculate `cum_time`.

Comment: @RonakShah This code works under the assumption that the shift number increments after each rest, i.e,  if `df$shift_number[14]` is `0` then the next nonzero shift number should be `4`.